# Don't attach file and send by email

Tags: android, kotlin, sendmail, android-fileprovider

I define FileProvider in manifest:

```
<provider
  android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="root"
  android:exported="false"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
</provider>
```

and write paths :

```
<files-path path="files/" name="files_name" />
```

I put file "1.txt" in "root"/files/1.txt

Created intent for send file by email:

```
val intentToSendToBd = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

val file = File(context.filesDir,"files/1.txt")

val ur = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "root", file )

intentToSendToBd.setType("text/plain")

intentToSendToBd.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, ur)

intentToSendToBd.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

intentToSendToBd.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
```

And finally I get "couldn't attach file"  in EmailApp.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to share mp3 file using send_imtent

```
    val sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    val directory = File(sdCard.absolutePath + "/Demo Mobile/VoiceMail")
    val f = File(directory, sharingFileName + ".mp3") //or any other format supported
    **val uri = Uri.parse("file://" + f.absolutePath)**
    val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
    share.setType("audio/mp3")
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Voicemail File"))
```

Thanks, Happy Coding...

Comment: I thinked  need to use FileProvider for  internal files. 
When I write **val uri = Uri.parse("file://" + f.absolutePath)** I get "Permissions denied for this attachment"